# Distinction between BackColor and ForeColor

Tags: vba, excel, colors, powerpoint

This is more of a conceptual question than a code issue.  When coloring shapes with VBA, I've always used the `ForeColor` property as a force of habit, but now I am curious as to how `BackColor` functions.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245036(v=vs.60).aspx) really doesn't provide much specificity as to the distinction.  The only pertinent information I can see there is:

> If you set the **BackColor** property on a **Form** object or a **PictureBox** control, all text and graphics, including the persistent graphics, are erased. Setting the **ForeColor** property doesn't affect graphics or print output already drawn.

which really doesn't seem to adequately explain the difference between them.

I did a bit of experimentation with setting the Back and Fore colors of shapes in different orders in the code and different text and other items contained, but I cannot for the life of me find any sort of consistent difference.  Frankly, it seems like the `BackColor` property is entirely useless, since `ForeColor`has seemed to just write over whatever color there is.

Does anyone know a good way to explain the difference between them (or a source of better documentation where I can read up on the differences)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BackColour is used when you apply the TwoColorGradient method.

For example, if you select a shape in PowerPoint and type this:

```
?ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Fill.BackColor
```

You'll probably see 16777215 (white) returned and if you change it to red, you'll see no change:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255,0,0)
```

But if you apply the gradient method:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Fill.TwoColorGradient _
  msoGradientDiagonalUp, 1
```

And then change the BackColor, you'll see a change.

Comment: You, sir, are a saint.  To clarify, is the `TwoColorGradient` property the _only_ thing that uses BackColor, or is that just a primary use?

Comment: Pattern fills also use BackColor.  In fact, if you give a shape a pattern fill, you can choose Foreground Color and Background Color.